# Cannot compile my app with few classes from the Google Mac Toolbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

UPDATE:

Here is more detailed compiler output:

[image]

---

So I am working on a simple app. I want to be able to do some encoding/decoding of strings, so I have added these three files from the Google Mac ToolBox to my project:

- GTMDefines.h
- GTMNSString+HTML.h
- GTMNSString+HTML.m

Since my project uses ARC, I have added the files to the build phases and set the -fno-objc-arc flag so they don't compile with ARC. See the screenshot:

[image]

Now I go to my main view controller and add this line:

```
#import "GTMNSString+HTML.m"
```

And I try to compile my project. I get errors like these:

[image]

How can I solve this? I am new to iOS development so please explain well.

Comment: Looks absolutely OK. With older versions of XCode I sometimes got errors like these, but while editing files. They disappeared during building and returned right after successful build. Which XCode version are you using?

Comment: If I were you I would try updating to the current Xcode version.

Comment: @PeterG. I can't. I am running Snow Leopard. The lates Xcode available for Snow Leopard is 4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To get rid of the first two warnings (no rule to process file...) remove GTMDefines.h and GTMNSString+HTML.h from your "Compile sources". Only .m-files need to be there.
2. You never want to import .m files, even if it's technically possible! To get rid of your errors, change your import from

   ```
   #import "GTMNSString+HTML.m"
   ```

   to

   ```
   #import "GTMNSString+HTML.h"
   ```

Comment: I have posted a new screenshot. Check my question.

Comment: Guess I don't need that screenshot any more. Check the last update to my answer, that will solve your problem.